# A query to determine if a column is computed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get List of Computed Columns in Database Table (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484147/get-list-of-computed-columns-in-database-table-sql-server)

In SQL Server 2008 is there a stored procedure I can run or view I can query which shows whether a column is a computed column? I've tried querying `information_schema.columns` but it doesn't seem to provide this information.

Comment: Duplicate of [Get List of Computed Columns in Database Table (SQL Server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484147/get-list-of-computed-columns-in-database-table-sql-server). The ANSI INFORMATION_SCHEMA isn't the right place to be looking--dunno if there's such thing as an ANSI computed column so the native tables in SQL Server are the place to look.