# How to detect if a column is a computed column

Tags: java, sql-server-2000, calculated-columns

I'm working with SQL Server 2000 and Java.

I am creating an application that, among other things, reads the metadata from the tables, recreates them at another server and carry the data.

One of the tables was created this way:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
    Date datetime NOT NULL,     
    Code int NOT NULL,
    SameCodeAgainWTF AS Code 
)
```

How do I detect that the "**SameCodeAgainWTF**" column is a computed column so I don't try to insert values at it during the data migration phase?

I already got the DatabaseMetaData object from the connection. But I was unable to find a method that gives me that information.

```
...
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
...
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

I want to know if there is a solution without running another query. If there is a way to get the information from the DatabaseMetaData or the ResultSetMetaData.

I know I can query the syscolumns but I want to avoid it.

```
SELECT 
    sysobjects.name AS TableName, 
    syscolumns.name AS ColumnName
FROM syscolumns
    INNER JOIN sysobjects
    ON syscolumns.id = sysobjects.id
    AND sysobjects.xtype = 'U' --User Tables
WHERE syscolumns.iscomputed = 1
```

[From: Get List of Computed Columns in Database Table (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484147/get-list-of-computed-columns-in-database-table-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query [syscolumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260398%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) which contains an `iscomputed` column.

```
SELECT o.name as TableName, c.name as ComputedColumnName
    FROM sysobjects o
        INNER JOIN syscolumns c
            ON o.id = c.id
                AND c.iscomputed = 1
    WHERE o.xtype = 'u'
```

Comment: "SELECT * FROM dbo.syscolumns WHERE iscomputed = 1" I saw that solution, but I wanna know if there is a way to get that information from the DatabaseMetaData or from a ResultSetMetaData without having to write another query for that.

Comment: Since no other answers were posted, I'll accept yours as the only way. But, in my program, I ended up using the isReadOnly method from the RecordSetMetaData.