# How to find Computed field in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

`field1` in `table1` is computed. So when you run

```
sp_help table1
```

In the column result set the computed field column for field1 is set to 'yes'.

How I can find whether a column is computed from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` or anywhere else? It doesn't seem to be here:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get List of Computed Columns in Database Table (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484147/get-list-of-computed-columns-in-database-table-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you require that information for all colums, you can obtain it using `sys.columns` e.g.

```
select C.name, c.is_computed -- try c.* to see all info
from sys.columns c
where c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('table1')
```

If you only need that information for a single column you can obtain it using `COLUMNPROPERTY` e.g.

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('table1'),'field1','IsComputed')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? `SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE is_computed = 1`

Comment: just add AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('table1')  if you want to search only the computed columns from table 1